# Error: Connection Closed - MongoDB Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Okay so I'm a total Node/MongoDB newbie and I'm currently following this tutorial: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html .

This is the code I have thusfar

```
    var MongoClient = require('mongoDB').MongoClient;

    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:8888/exampleDb", function(err, db){
        if( !err ){
             console.log("We are connected");
        } else console.log(err);
    });
```

However when I run node /node/index.js my console logs:

```
    [Error: connection closed]
```

I've tried disabling my firewall and adding auto-reconnect: true, both which didn't work. I can't seem to find the problem online, what could be wrong?

EDIT: this is how I set up the server

```
    var server = require("./server");
    var router = require("./router");

    // in router.js
    function route(handle, pathname, response){
        console.log("About to route a request for "+pathname);
        if( typeof handle[pathname] === "function"){
            handle[pathname](response);
        } else {
            console.log("404");
            response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
            response.write("404 not found");
            response.end();
        }
    }

    exports.route = route;

    // in server.js
    var http = require("http");
    var url = require("url");

    function start(route, handle){
        function onRequest(request, response){
            var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
            route(handle, pathname, response);
        }

        http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    }
    exports.start = start;

    server.start(router.route, handle);
```

Comment: try in your console `mongo localhost/exampleDb --port 8888` to see if you can connect normally in your mongoDb instance

Comment: Are you able to connect to mongod using mongo client on 8888 port?

Comment: I'm unsure how I would run that code. After I do "node /node/index.js" I get the "console.logs" but am then unable to type anything unless I close the command prompt. If I type it before the "node /node/index.js" I get an error that "mongo" is not recognized as a command.

Comment: I have added the code which I use to set up a server

Comment: have you lanched mongod ? `sudo service mongodb start`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, your error is simple. By default, mongoDB run at port 27017 and in your code, you try to connect on mongod instance on 8888 port. This port is used for your node project, not for MongoDB.

To first, you should launch mongod instance. If you're in Ubuntu, you can start with this :

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

If you are in another platform, and the mongodb path is in your PATH env, you can launch this simply whith this command :

```
mongod
```

Change the connection uri by :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongoDB').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db){
    if( !err ){
         console.log("We are connected");
    } else console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: If I do this I get [Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]

Answer (score 1):

Woops false alarm, I hadn't launched mongod.exe yet. So for anyone that encounters this error and searches the web: make sure you've installed mongodb and run the mongod.exe executable inside the installation/bin directory